difference between possessive pronoun or possessive adjective case of his

She insisted on his leaving the house.

Is his possessive pronoun or possessive adjective?

Try swapping the genders

He insisted on her leaving the house.

With gerund/participle clauses, the subject can be in the possessive.  The reason for this is an analogy with noun phrases.  A noun phrase can take a determiner "her {thing}".  The determiner in a noun phrase appears in the same position as the subject in a clause: at the front. If a sentence is used with a gerund instead of a noun phrase, the subject of the gerund can be the same form as the determiner.
In your terminology this is a "possessive adjective"  (but it isn't an adjective, so I avoid this term).
With the feminine gender this is significant, as "her" has a different form from "hers"  But in the masculine, both have the same form "his", and so it doesn't matter.

Difference between Possessive determiner and Possessive pronoun.
OP's query:

She insisted on his leaving the house. Here his is possessive pronoun or possessive adjective ?

The terminology used to describe words like my, his, her, our, your, their is possessive determiner. Like adjectives, determiners also modify a noun. "His" can be a Possessive determiner or a Possessive pronoun. We know that it is a Possessive determiner when it comes before the noun they modify.

https://youtu.be/-ZU7_TF9JSY?si=NJf1-ZHeUeg6Ddnb
[![difference between a Possessive determiner and a Possessive pronoun][1]][1]

Here the word "his" appears before the gerund (noun) phrase "leaving the house". So as we explained above, here "his" is a  Possessive determiner.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/iVRL8i6j.jpg
